# Java TableCellListener causing an array index out of bound error

Tags: java, jtable

I wrote a program which uses the `TableCellListener` class.

The code compiles properly but when i run the program I get the following error when I navigate from cell to cell using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" 
                           java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
```

This only happens when I use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key. If I use the mouse the program works perfectly. Another user ran the exact same program on his computer and wasn't able to duplicate the problem. Everything ran perfectly. He was using Windows but I'm using a Mac. Has anyone else had this problem with `TableCellListener`?

Here is the code:

```
package testyo;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.text.*;


public class Testyo {
JFrame mainPanel;
RXTable myTable;
DefaultTableModel myTableModel;

Testyo() {
    mainPanel = new JFrame();
    mainPanel.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    mainPanel.setSize(1200, 1200);
    mainPanel.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    String[] columnNames = {"ID", "First Name", "Last Name", "Salary"};
    Object[][] data = {
        {1, "aaa", "bbb", 2000}, 
        {2, "ccc", "ddd", 2300},
        {3, "eee", "fff", 1900}
    };
    myTable = new RXTable(new MyTableModel(data, columnNames));
    myTable.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
    myTable.setSelectAllForEdit(true);
    JScrollPane myScrollPane = new JScrollPane(myTable);
    myTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(1000, 400));
    mainPanel.getContentPane().add(myScrollPane);
    mainPanel.setVisible(true);


    Action action = new AbstractAction () {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            TableCellListener tcl = (TableCellListener)e.getSource();
            System.out.println("***");                         
        }
    };
    TableCellListener tcl = new TableCellListener(myTable, action);
}


class MyTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

    public MyTableModel(Object[][] data, String[] columnNames) {
        super(data, columnNames);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        return !(col==0);
    }

    @Override
    public Class getColumnClass(int col) {
        if (col == 0 | col == 3)
            return Integer.class;
        else
            return String.class;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           new Testyo();
       } 
    });
}
}
```

And here is the full stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at java.util.Vector.elementData(Vector.java:730)
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:473)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:649)
at testyo.TableCellListener.run(TableCellListener.java:145)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at java.util.Vector.elementData(Vector.java:730)
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:473)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:649)
at testyo.TableCellListener.processEditingStopped(TableCellListener.java:154)
at testyo.TableCellListener.propertyChange(TableCellListener.java:121)
at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(PropertyChangeSupport.java:335)
at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:327)
at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:263)
at java.awt.Component.firePropertyChange(Component.java:8382)
at javax.swing.JTable.setCellEditor(JTable.java:5633)
at javax.swing.JTable.removeEditor(JTable.java:5822)
at javax.swing.JTable.editingStopped(JTable.java:4723)
at javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor.fireEditingStopped(AbstractCellEditor.java:141)
at javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor$EditorDelegate.stopCellEditing(DefaultCellEditor.java:368)
at javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor.stopCellEditing(DefaultCellEditor.java:233)
at javax.swing.JTable$GenericEditor.stopCellEditing(JTable.java:5477)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI$Actions.actionPerformed(BasicTableUI.java:502)
at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(SwingUtilities.java:1664)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(JComponent.java:2879)
at javax.swing.JTable.processKeyBinding(JTable.java:5258)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(JComponent.java:2940)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2842)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6282)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1895)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:762)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1027)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:899)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:727)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4731)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: TableCellListener is not a standard class. We have no idea what it does. And you didn't post the exception stack trace either. So we're completely in the dark.

Comment: I added the entire error message.

Comment: But we still don't know anything about the TableCellListener class.

Comment: My program initially added a TableModelListener and I used the tableChanged method. However, this method is called even if no editing was done in the cell. The TableCellListener on the other hand is called only when the cell has been actually edited and it also gives us access to both the new and old values of the cell. the following link is where I got the class from: http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/table-cell-listener/